# Drupal 7 Module "Page Title" Malfunctioning

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7, page-title

I have installed and configure a module called Page Title in Drupal 7. The problem is when I edit a page and set the page title from the option provided by the respective module, the title doesn't change and remains the same as mentioned in the default page title in module configuration page.

In short the module is not over-writing the default title by the custom title.

Regards
Umair

Comment: What is the pattern that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

On the modules list page (`admin/modules`) you should have a link to `Configure` your Page Title module to tell it how to give titles to your pages.  The configuration page should look something like the image below.  It sounds like you have not yet configured this so it's still giving you the default titles.

[image: Page title - Configure]

Comment: @mnc: No, its not the case. I have configured the module through this page I have checked the boxes for events, pages, blogs, articles and etc and also defined the default title using the tokens. But the problem is that I when I write a custom title it doesn't replace the default one.

Comment: @mnc: The site has been developed by another team of developers and they have done a lot of customization is there any possibility that some customization is over-riding the default behavior of the module ?